# Span left align text "around" other span text

Tags: css

I have a display for a user's comment.

I want the username to be displayed (with a different style) and then the comment to be display after on the same line (and the following lines if necessary)

Here is a fiddle for where I am now:

https://jsfiddle.net/41y6ycf4/3/

Here is the code that is at the fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<span class="user">Remus </span>
<span class="comment"> This is my user's comment And I am making it large so that it makes sense for this example</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.user {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.comment {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #999999;
}
```

I realize that if I get rid of the `display: block` and the `text-align: left` it will look exactly as I want it on the fiddle.

But, I must explicitly define the left align because I have many other default styles on my site that are currently aligning it centered.

**EDIT 1**

It seems for spans that if you do not define the display as block or inline-block, then the text-align does not take effect. But if I do define display that way then it makes a new line for the comment (not what I want)

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/41y6ycf4/7/?

Comment: Yes, thanks @NenadVracar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating the name does what you want:

```
.user {
font-weight: 900;
float: left;
}
```